# Ionic Cordova Printer error

Tags: printing, ionic-framework, ngcordova

i am trying to use the cordova printer plugin from: https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-printer/tree/master

I have followed the installation instructions and have this in index.html:

```
<script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js"></script>
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

Here is my controller call:

```
$scope.printTable = function(){
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    cordova.plugins.printer.isAvailable(
        function (isAvailable) {
            alert(isAvailable ? 'Service is available' : 'Service NOT available');
        });
     })
  };
```

i get this error on phonegap app:

```
Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'cordova.plugins.printer')
```

I have this added in my config.xml file:

```
    <gap:plugin name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.printer" version="0.7.0" />
```

What am i missing here

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.print = function() {
    if ($cordovaPrinter.isAvailable()) {
        $cordovaPrinter.print(//type what to display);
    } else {
        alert("Printing is not available on device");
    }
}
```

just try like this